Is the Jordan normal form uniquely determined by the characteristic and minimal polynomial if they are the same?
I'm studying for an exam and I can't get anywhere with a problem. I've seen similar questions on here but not the same.
The problem provides the characteristic polynomial $XA(x) = (x-3)^2(x-1)$ and the minimal polynomial $p(x) = (x-3)^2(x-1)$.
The related question is whether these two things determine the Jordan normal form? If so, what is it?
I know that the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial do not necessarily define the Jordan normal form as other people have already asked that question. However in this case, they are the same. Is there a special way of reasoning here?
Some help would be great!

Yes.
Looking at the eigenvalue 3, the power of $(x-3)$ in the minimal polynomial is 2, which means there must be at least one Jordan block of size 2 corresponding to the eigenvalue 3.
Therefore the Jordan normal form must be $\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ (or $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$, swapping the two Jordan blocks).
In general, if the minimal polynomial is equal to the characteristic polynomial, the Jordan normal form will simply have one Jordan block for each eigenvalue, with size equal to the (algebraic) multiplicity (power in the characteristic polynomial) of that eigenvalue.
For eigenvalues $\lambda$ with multiplicity no greater than 6, the Jordan blocks corresponding to $\lambda$ can be uniquely determined by the relevant parts of the characteristic and minimal polynomials (namely, the power of $(x-\lambda)$ in each), along with the dimension of the eigenspace $E(\lambda)$ (as this will be equal to the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to $\lambda$).
In case you are wondering why this is not necessarily enough information when the multiplicity is greater than 6:
Suppose we have a matrix with characteristic polynomial $(x-5)^7$, minimal polynomial $(x-5)^3$, and $\text{dim } E(5) = 3$. We know the largest Jordan block will have size 3, because 3 is the power of $(x-5)$ in the minimal polynomial. We know there are 3 Jordan blocks, because $\text{dim } E(5) = 3$. Finally, we know that the sizes of all the Jordan blocks add up to 7, because this is the algebraic multiplicity (this is a fact about the Jordan normal form). Once we fill in the largest Jordan block, of size 3, we have have a 4x4 space remaining:
(zeroes outside Jordan blocks omitted from the following matrices for readability)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\
0 & 5 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
0 & 0 & 5 &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & 5 & ? &   &   \\
  &   &   &   & 5 & ? &   \\
  &   &   &   &   & 5 & ? \\
  &   &   &   &   &   & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$
This could be filled in two ways - either with another block of size 3 and a final block of size 1, like so:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\
0 & 5 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
0 & 0 & 5 &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & 5 & 1 & 0 &   \\
  &   &   & 0 & 5 & 1 &   \\
  &   &   & 0 & 0 & 5 &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$
Or, with two blocks of size 2, like so:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & 0 &   &   &   &   \\
0 & 5 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
0 & 0 & 5 &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & 5 & 1 &   &   \\
  &   &   & 0 & 5 &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   & 5 & 1 \\
  &   &   &   &   & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$
To figure out which one it is, we can use the dimension of the second generalised eigenspace, but I think this is beyond the scope of this question. I hope this fully answers your question!

Let $f\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ be monic of degree $n\ge 1$, and let
$$
S=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}){\,\mid\,}\text{minpoly}(A)=f\}
$$
Claim:$\;$All elements of $S$ have the same Jordan normal form.

Proof:

Choose $A\in S$ and let $J$ be the Jordan normal form for $A$.

Write $f$ as
$$
f=(x-\lambda_1)^{k_1}\cdots(x-\lambda_m)^{k_m}
$$
where $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\in\mathbb{C}$ are the distinct roots of $f$, and
$k_1,...,k_m$ are positive integers such that $k_1+\cdots+k_m=n$.

Since $J$ is conjugate to $A$, we get that $f$ is also the minimal polynomial of $J$.

It follows that

$\qquad$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices

for each $i\in\{1,...,m\}$, the size of the largest Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda_i$ is equal to $k_i$.

But then since $k_1+\cdots+k_m=n$, it follows that the Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda_i$ of size $k_i$ is the only Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

Thus $J$ is uniquely determined, requiring no information about $A$ other than $A\in S$.
